# Unable to rename a disk image on a Mac

Tags: mac, dropbox, osx-el-capitan, disk-utility

I tried renaming the disk image but after I close the "get Info" window it changes back to "Disk Name 1" instead of "Disk Name"

I tried renaming it from Terminal, so now it gets renamed to "Disk Name 2"

Dropbox won't open because it is located in /Volumes/Disk Name/Dropbox

Disk Utilities Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So how can I change it back to it's original Name.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by opening an application which shows all the hidden/system files. (in my case FileZilla did the job). this way I was able to access the folder "Volumes" as shown in the image.

I found 2 duplicates of the "Disk Name" each given an additional number.

I removed them and it worked again.

[FileZilla Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwRo4.png)